# Converging sequence with sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the sequence $x_{k+1} := f(x_k)$, for $k \geq 1$, such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = \bar{x} = f(\bar{x})$.

Suppose that there exists a unique fixed point $\bar{x} = f(\bar{x})$.

Now consider the sequence $y_{k+1} := f\left( \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i  \right)$, $k \geq 1$, with $y_1 = x_1$.

Say if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} y_k = \bar{x}$.

Comment. This question is a variant of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582493/sequence-with-a-contraction-mapping-of-the-sum).

Comment: $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $n=1$. Let $f(1)=f(-1)=-1$ and $f(0)=0$, put $x_1=1$. Then $x_k=-1$ for all $k\ge2$, $y_2=-1$, and $y_k=0$ for all $k\ge3$.

Comment: Thanks. What instead if there exists a unique fixed point?

Comment: Then it becomes a bit trickier. Of course, if $(y_k)$ converges, then the limit *must* be the fixed point, so one would have to look for examples in which $(y_k)$ diverges. I am pretty sure you need $n\ge2$ for a counterexample in that case.